# Visual Studio Code can't run in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I have been using VSCode for a while and never had any big problem with it. Today I tried to start my VSCode from left taskbar on my Ubuntu 18.04 and it not showing up. Also, I tried to run in terminal as 'code .' again nothing.

VSCode version is latest 1.23.1 I tried few time today with install/remove and nothing. Somehow I am thinking maybe it something with permissions but not sure. 
When click on task bar icon its shows like loading on top taskbar in ubuntu 18.04 for a few seconds and stops.

Also when tried to run in terminal as:

```
$ code . --verbose
[15027:0603/191139.702752:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
[15027:0603/191139.809312:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: GModule (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/immodules/im-ibus.so) initialization check failed: GLib version too old (micro mismatch)
[15027:0603/191139.809326:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: Loading IM context type 'ibus' failed
pcilib: Cannot open /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:07:00.0/resource: No such file or directory
```

just getting an error, but not sure is this error connected with problem I did some investigation and Gtk is already installed and works well on my OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it with "delete the `/home/user/.config/Code` folder"

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/55774#issuecomment-412774473